# gcc is gone probably after an update

Tags: apt, updates, compiling, gcc

gcc was installed in my system at the start, I still remember using it but after some time it was gone and replaced by some other versions of `gcc`.

When I type in `gcc` from the terminal several suggestions were displayed (*gcc-4.8*, *gcc-ar-4.8*, *gcc-nm-4.8*, *gcc-ranlib-4.8*).

I'm not familiar with any of them but I think gcc-4.8 is a new version of gcc, I tried to use it to compile a program and it worked the same with `gcc`.

I would like to know if this is because of a system update I did recently and why does Ubuntu have this kind of program replacement.

Additionally, how can I run `gcc` like how I used to before (using the `gcc` program). I'm thinking of making a link to the gcc-4.8 and naming it `gcc` but I'm open for best practices or your personal suggestions.

Comment: Just double checking, but have you tried doing $ sudo apt-get install gcc

Comment: yes, I can do that but  don't see the need to because the program is already installed in just a newer version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/usr/bin/gcc` is just a symbolic link, eg:

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mär 12 17:28 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.9
```

Why the link on your system does not exist (anymore), we can only speculate about it.

You have two options:

- Create the symbolic link

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc
  ```

or

- Reinstall the package `gcc`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc
  ```

I would prefer the second option.

Comment: It's weird why it just disappeared. Would reinstalling gcc just do the same as with the symbolic link or will it install an outdated version of gcc?

Comment: @krato Thus, the current version is reinstalled or a newer version, if there is one. The current version for Trusty is 4.8 but 4.9 for Utopic, Vivid and Wily.

Comment: I did what you suggested and did a `gcc --version` and true enough it installed the latest(4.8). Anyway I'm still open for answers on possible reasons gcc was suddenly removed.

Comment: gcc wasn't really removed; it was the symbolic link named `gcc` that was removed.

Comment: Well I guess that is true because if `gcc` was indeed removed, it should still show the broken link. Still no clue why symbolic link was suddenly gone.

Comment: gcc **is** the link. A broken link is only shown, when the target doesn't exist.